# Taking multiple strings through scanf

Tags: c

When I try to use `scanf()` to read one string of chars, everything works.

In the code below, I read two strings of chars, but if I input `"abcde abcde"` (arbitrary letters), `printf()` prints `" is your character"`.

```
int main(){
   char A[5], B[5];
   scanf("%s %s", A,B);
   printf("%c is your character", A[0]);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The array `char A[5]` is long enough for a string 4-chars long. Remember the array needs an *extra* element for the terminating `'\0'`. By writing 5 characters in `A` (`"abcde"`) you invoke **UB** because there is no room for the `'\0'`. Try `scanf("%4s%4s", A, B);` or increase the size of the arrays.

Comment: "everything works" <== nope, not really. That's one of the characteristics of **UB** (Undefined Behavior). It may work as you expect even though it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are typing one string of length 5 (+1 with \0) and try to put it in a char table of size 5, which is an undefined behavior.
If you want to put “abcde” in both A and B, you need to increase the size of A and B to at least 6.

Comment: @ravenspoint: the answer was completely rewritten after my comment.

Answer (score 0):

As @pmg pointed out already, the char array has to be long enough to have the `null-terminator` at the end of it, thus `abcde abcde` doesn't work, but `abcd abcd` works. If you would like to solve this statically, literally just stretch the size of the array buy how much you need:

```
char A[40], B[40];
```

However, if you really insist on getting dynamic allocation, you could use `getline()`, then `malloc` on some `char*` of the length of your input string (worst case scenario), and then use `sscanf` to split your input stringo to A and B.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char* I = NULL;
    char* A;
    char* B;
    size_t len = 0;

    if (getline(&I, &len, stdin) != EOF)
    {
        A = (char*)malloc(len + 1);
        B = (char*)malloc(len + 1);
        sscanf(I, "%s %s", A, B);
        printf("%c is your character", A[0]);
        free(A);
        free(B);
    }

    free(I);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `getline` is a Posix interface not in standard C. That's 100% fine in my book. But if you're going to require Posix, then save yourself a lot of work and use the `m` modifier in the scanf conversions. There are other good reasons to use `getline`, but if it's only to manage memory, the `%ms` conversion code is sufficient and you can just use `scanf`. Even if you do decide on `getline` + `sscanf`, `%ms`  makes your life simpler.